# Reference request for dinatural transformations arising from free Cartesian closed categories

Tags: reference-request, lo.logic, cartesian-closed-categories

Let $g_n$ be a discrete graph with $n$ nodes and $\operatorname{F}$ the free functor of the adjunction between the category of graphs and the category of Cartesian closed categories and functors, as defined in [Introduction to Higher Order Categorical Logic](https://www.cambridge.org/us/universitypress/subjects/mathematics/logic-categories-and-sets/introduction-higher-order-categorical-logic) part 1, section 4. Then $\mathbf{CCC}_n = \operatorname{F}\ g_n$ becomes the Cartesian closed category freely generated from $g_n$.

For any Cartesian closed category $\mathbf{C}$, has anyone defined a mapping from objects in $m_1, m_2 \in \mathbf{CCC}_n$ to multivariant functors $\operatorname{M_1}, \operatorname{M_2} \in (\mathbf{C}^\text{op})^n \times \mathbf{C}^n \to \mathbf{C}$ and arrows $t \in m_1 \to m_2$ to dinatural transformations $\alpha : \operatorname{M_1} \stackrel{\cdot}{\to} \operatorname{M_2}$?